# Simple Pie Chart in Core Animation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I'm trying to include a simple pie chart in my app using Core Animation.
I found an article on-line to copy and adjust, which seems to be close to what I need.

https://github.com/tomnoda/piechart_ios

The code refers to Nib files (which I don't really understand), but can I do this programmatically instead? I think this is the line of code that needs to change, and maybe I need to add some other coding as well:-

```
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
         let view: UIView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PieChartView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! UIView
     addSubview(view)
```

The let line refers to the Nib file, but how can I get it to refer to my View Controller instead?
This obviously results in  a series of unresolved identifier errors, as the 2 files aren't linked as they should be. On the View Controller I have the following, as well as a number of other outlets:-

```
    @IBOutlet weak var  pieChartView: PieChartView!
```

As I'm new to Xcode hopefully there is a simple fix to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I'm trying to include a **simple** pie chart in my app using Core Animation"*

First, remove the word ***simple*** from that statement. Not to sound like a jerk, but if you are a beginner and don't even understand elements laid-out in a nib (xib) vs creating elements via code, you will have a long road ahead of you.

While the example you linked to "works," it has a lot of limitations and takes some rather odd approaches to the task. For example:

- it is limited to 5 or fewer segments
- the sum of the segment values must equal 1.0
- it has very little in the way of error checking

That said, it *could* be a good place for you to start learning.

Here is the same code, modified to NOT need the xib file. It can be used like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var pieChartView: MyPieChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pieChartView.slices = [
            Slice(percent: 0.4, color: UIColor.red),
            Slice(percent: 0.3, color: UIColor.blue),
            Slice(percent: 0.2, color: UIColor.purple),
            Slice(percent: 0.1, color: UIColor.green)
        ]
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        pieChartView.animateChart()
    }
}
```

This is `MyPieChartView.swift` ...

First changes from the original `PieChartView.swift` file are at the top, between the:

```
// MARK: Changes start here
// MARK: Changes end here
```

Additional changes to allow "anti-clockwise" ... look for instances of new Bool var `drawClockwise`

```
import UIKit

class MyPieChartView: UIView {

    static let ANIMATION_DURATION: CGFloat = 1.4

// MARK: Changes start here
    var canvasView: UIView!

    var label1: UILabel!
    var label2: UILabel!
    var label3: UILabel!
    var label4: UILabel!
    var label5: UILabel!

    var label1XConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var label2XConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var label3XConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var label4XConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var label5XConst: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var label1YConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var label2YConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var label3YConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var label4YConst: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var label5YConst: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var drawClockwise: Bool = true

    var slices: [Slice]?
    var sliceIndex: Int = 0
    var currentPercent: CGFloat = 0.0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        if canvasView == nil {

            let container = UIView()
            addSubview(container)

            canvasView = UIView()
            container.addSubview(canvasView)

            canvasView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                canvasView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor),
                canvasView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor),
                canvasView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor),
                canvasView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor),
            ])

            canvasView.backgroundColor = .yellow

            label1 = UILabel()
            label2 = UILabel()
            label3 = UILabel()
            label4 = UILabel()
            label5 = UILabel()

            [label1, label2, label3, label4, label5].forEach {
                guard let v = $0 else { fatalError("Bad Setup!") }
                v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                v.textColor = .white
                v.textAlignment = .center
                addSubview(v)
            }

            label1XConst = label1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerXAnchor)
            label1YConst = label1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerYAnchor)

            label2XConst = label2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerXAnchor)
            label2YConst = label2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerYAnchor)

            label3XConst = label3.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerXAnchor)
            label3YConst = label3.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerYAnchor)

            label4XConst = label4.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerXAnchor)
            label4YConst = label4.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerYAnchor)

            label5XConst = label5.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerXAnchor)
            label5YConst = label5.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasView.centerYAnchor)

            [label1XConst, label2XConst, label3XConst, label4XConst, label5XConst,
             label1YConst, label2YConst, label3YConst, label4YConst, label5YConst].forEach {
                $0?.isActive = true
            }
        }

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        subviews[0].frame = bounds
    }

    // don't do this
    //override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    //  subviews[0].frame = bounds
    //}
// MARK: Changes end here

    /// Get an animation duration for the passed slice.
    /// If slice share is 40%, for example, it returns 40% of total animation duration.
    ///
    /// - Parameter slice: Slice struct
    /// - Returns: Animation duration
    func getDuration(_ slice: Slice) -> CFTimeInterval {
        return CFTimeInterval(slice.percent / 1.0 * PieChartView.ANIMATION_DURATION)
    }

    /// Convert slice percent to radian.
    ///
    /// - Parameter percent: Slice percent (0.0 - 1.0).
    /// - Returns: Radian
    func percentToRadian(_ percent: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        //Because angle starts wtih X positive axis, add 270 degrees to rotate it to Y positive axis.
        var angle = 270 + percent * 360
        if angle >= 360 {
            angle -= 360
        }
        return angle * CGFloat.pi / 180.0
    }

    /// Add a slice CAShapeLayer to the canvas.
    ///
    /// - Parameter slice: Slice to be drawn.
    func addSlice(_ slice: Slice) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.duration = getDuration(slice)
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
        animation.delegate = self

        let canvasWidth = canvasView.frame.width
        let toPercent = currentPercent + (drawClockwise ? slice.percent : -slice.percent)
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: canvasView.center,
                                radius: canvasWidth * 3 / 8,
                                startAngle: percentToRadian(currentPercent),
                                endAngle: percentToRadian(toPercent),
                                clockwise: drawClockwise)

        let sliceLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        sliceLayer.path = path.cgPath
        sliceLayer.fillColor = nil
        sliceLayer.strokeColor = slice.color.cgColor
        sliceLayer.lineWidth = canvasWidth * 2 / 8
        sliceLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        sliceLayer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)

        canvasView.layer.addSublayer(sliceLayer)
    }

    /// Get label's center position based on from and to percentages.
    /// This is always relative to canvasView's center.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - fromPercent: End of previous slice.
    ///   - toPercent: End of current slice.
    /// - Returns: Center point for label.
    func getLabelCenter(_ fromPercent: CGFloat, _ toPercent: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let radius = canvasView.frame.width * 3 / 8
        let labelAngle = percentToRadian((toPercent - fromPercent) / 2 + fromPercent)
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: canvasView.center,
                                radius: radius,
                                startAngle: labelAngle,
                                endAngle: labelAngle,
                                clockwise: drawClockwise)
        path.close()
        return path.currentPoint
    }

    /// Re-position and draw label such as "43%".
    ///
    /// - Parameter slice: Slice whose label is drawn.
    func addLabel(_ slice: Slice) {
        let center = canvasView.center
        let labelCenter = getLabelCenter(currentPercent, currentPercent + (drawClockwise ? slice.percent : -slice.percent))
        let xConst = [label1XConst, label2XConst, label3XConst, label4XConst, label5XConst][sliceIndex]
        let yConst = [label1YConst, label2YConst, label3YConst, label4YConst, label5YConst][sliceIndex]
        xConst?.constant = labelCenter.x - center.x
        yConst?.constant = labelCenter.y - center.y

        let label = [label1, label2, label3, label4, label5][sliceIndex]
        label?.isHidden = true
        label?.text = String(format: "%d%%", Int(slice.percent * 100))
    }

    /// Call this to start pie chart animation.
    func animateChart() {
        sliceIndex = 0
        currentPercent = 0.0
        canvasView.layer.sublayers = nil

        if slices != nil && slices!.count > 0 {
            let firstSlice = slices![0]
            addLabel(firstSlice)
            addSlice(firstSlice)
        }
    }
}

extension MyPieChartView: CAAnimationDelegate {
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            currentPercent += (drawClockwise ? slices![sliceIndex].percent : -slices![sliceIndex].percent)
            sliceIndex += 1
            if sliceIndex < slices!.count {
                let nextSlice = slices![sliceIndex]
                addLabel(nextSlice)
                addSlice(nextSlice)
            } else {
                //After animation is done, display all labels. Can be animated.
                for label in [label1, label2, label3, label4, label5] {
                    label?.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var pieChartView: MyPieChartView!
    @IBOutlet var antiPieChartView: MyPieChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pieChartView.slices = [
            Slice(percent: 0.4, color: UIColor.red),
            Slice(percent: 0.3, color: UIColor.blue),
            Slice(percent: 0.2, color: UIColor.purple),
            Slice(percent: 0.1, color: UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.75, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0))
        ]

        antiPieChartView.slices = [
            Slice(percent: 0.4, color: UIColor.red),
            Slice(percent: 0.3, color: UIColor.blue),
            Slice(percent: 0.2, color: UIColor.purple),
            Slice(percent: 0.1, color: UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.75, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0))
        ]

        // draw this pie anti-clockwise
        antiPieChartView.drawClockwise = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        pieChartView.animateChart()
        antiPieChartView.animateChart()
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I've loaded this up now and it looks great.

Comment: Many thanks. I've loaded this up now and it looks great. Now that it's working, I've made few changes, one of which is for the path to run anti-clockwise rather than clockwise. I've changed the 2 clockwise references true to false, and it does now run anti-clockwise, but when it does it messes up the colours and percentages, which were originally working correctly. There must be something else to change to get it back to the correct data as per the sample slices in the view controller. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: @ColinD - as I said, this could be a good place for you to start learning. If you got the segments to draw anti-clockwise, you *should* be able to find where to change the label positioning -- it will be much the same as the change needed to calculate the slice angle changes. I edited my post with an option to set the chart to `.drawClockwise = false`, but take a bit more time to get it working on your own... then compare to what I did with it.

Comment: Thanks, this all works great now. There were more changes than I anticipated. I thought it would be a straightforward change of Clockwise true to false, but obviously more involved than that. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi, on the view controller I’ve tried to put calculated variables into the sample slice percentages, and I get an error ‘cannot convert value of type Int to expected argument type CGFloat’. The suggested fix doesn’t work either. Any idea how I can fix this? I’ve tried various options to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: @ColinD - if you have something like `var j: Int = 3` ... and you need to use `j` as a `CGFloat` ... use `CGFloat(j)`.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that and the error went away, but then I got a yellow error on the 'var J' line saying 'variable was never mutated, consider using a let'. But it needs to be a Var as this value will keep on changing,

Comment: @ColinD - *"needs to be a Var as this value will keep on changing"* ... well, if you are getting `variable was never mutated` warning, then you haven't written code that changes `J` yet. Xcode cannot guess what code you will write in the future.